# Error with Eclipse properties disabled

Tags: android, eclipse

Here is what I have done: Downloaded and installed android SDK, eclipse and added the google repo for developer tools. 
Issue is, when I got to Projects->Properties it is greyed out. 
I don't understand why? Here is an image for reference: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXzw7.png

I need to go into properties to make android SDK is installed properly. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Package explorer is empty. First create a new project `File->New->Android Application Project`. Then you can check `Projects->Properties`.

Or path to your android workspace is not proper.Select `File->Switch Workspace` to switch to proper workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Do right click on your project folder and click on the properties.Then you will able to find the property dialog box.
And after that the project ->property will be enable.